# What does the notation $\min_x$ mean?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, notation

I have a problem in which I need to find $\min_x(f(x))$. What does this notation mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the contexts I've seen, $\min_x(f(x))$ , means "the minimum of $f(x)$ over all $x$".

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means the minimum of the function $f$ when $x$ is varying over the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

$\min_{x\in A}f(x)$ it's just another way to write $\min\{f(x):x\in A\}$

Comment: What is A in the context of the question?